# Notify when all observables are completed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an array of observables. Each observable is a file which needs to be uploaded via HTTP request.

I want to do two things:

1. For each uploaded file I have to emit event which will be handled in parent component.
2. When all files are uploaded I have return notify that all observable are completed.

I started with this code:

```
this.isUploading$ = Observable.of(true);

const source$ = Observable.from(files)
    .concatMap(file => this.uploadSingleFile(file));

source$.subscribe(data => this.onSuccess.emit(data));
```

Observable `isUploading$` represent that upload process started and it is consumed in HTML. I want to display spinner based on the state of `isUploading$`.

Observable `source$` represents file uploads operations because method this.uploadSingleFile(file) with return `Observable<Response>`.

This code will upload all files and execute `this.onSuccess.emit(data)` on each completed observable.

The question is: How I can set `this.isUploading$` to `false` when everything is done?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to achieve something like this but without assigning variable in `onCompleted` function. Example:

```
source$.subscribe(data => this.onSuccess.emit(data),
                  err => console.log(err),
                  () => this.isUploading = false );
```

I want to retrieve two observables and subscribe to them later whenever I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run all of these observables concurrently, `concatMap` will not do what you want. You can do these two things with the `do` and `forkJoin` operators.

`forkJoin` is basically `Promise.all` for observables.

`do` is a way to tap into the values being passed through and observable so you can "do" something with them (a side-effect).

So:

```js
const arrayOfObservables = [observable1, observable2, observable3];

Observable.forkJoin(
  arrayOfObservables.map((obs, i) => obs.do({
    next(value) { console.log(`Observable ${i} emits: ${value}`); },
    complete() { console.log(`Observable ${i} is complete`); }
  }))
)
.subscribe(values => console.log('everything done with', values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need isUploading to be an observable? I'd do it like this:

```
this.isUploading = true;
const source$ = Observable.from(files)
    .concatMap(file => this.uploadSingleFile(file));

source$.subscribe(data => this.onSuccess.emit(data),
                  err => console.log(err),
                  () => this.isUploading = false );
```

Comment: I don't want to change state of `this.isUploading` inside observables. I would like to convert in observable if is possible. Is there any other way to do that rather than assigning false in `onCompleted` function?

Comment: Also this will get you into some trouble when using the `OnPush` changedetection-strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `BehaviorSubject` for it:

```
public isUploading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

...

```
this.isUploading$.next(false);
this.isUploading$.complete();
```

And use `forkJoin` operator to wait for all to complete:

```
const allSources$ = Observable.forkJoin(source$);
allSources$.subscribe(data => {
    this.isUploading$.next(false);
    this.isUploading$.complete();
}
```

This would give you the desired result.

Comment: Where I have to call `this.isUploading$.next(true);` ? How I know that all files are uploaded?

Comment: Call it at the same time when your calling `this.onSuccess.emit`.

Comment: `this.onSuccess.emit` is executed for each observable. I want to set `false` only when all operations are done.

Comment: Ah okay, mistinterpreted your example, use the `forkJoin` operator to wait for all Observables to complete. (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin)

Comment: Added it to my answer.