# Angular wait for multiple and chained request, then make a final POST request

Tags: angular, post, rxjs

The page is a form to create an Enterprise and 1 or more establishment to it.
Each establishment has an address.
I have to save all this.

So i have to loop over all establishments to save its address, then take the addressId sent by the backend and put it in the EnterpriseRequestModel, and then save the enterprise.

I have no idea how to make that, i guess it's some sort of combination of ForkJoin, MergeMap and all but i don't fully understand RxJs operators yet so i could use some help, thank you.

[EDIT]

Ok so right now the component doesn't support multiple establishments, there was only one establishment, and the function to save all this looks like this :

```
public onSave(): void {
this.isLoading = true;

const siren = this.entepriseWithEstablishmentFormGroup.controls.enterpriseFormGroup.controls.siren.value;
const enterprise = this.entepriseWithEstablishmentFormGroup.controls.enterpriseFormGroup.getRawValue();
const establishment = this.entepriseWithEstablishmentFormGroup.controls.establishmentFormGroup.getRawValue();
const siret = `${siren}${establishment.siret}`;
const establishmentRM = new EstablishmentRequestModel(establishment.name, siret, establishment.email, establishment.phone, null, establishment.addressId);
const enterpriseRM = new EnterpriseWithEstablishmentRequestModel(enterprise.name, enterprise.siren, establishmentRM);

this.isLoading = true;

// create enterprise and establishment in a row
this.subscriptions.add(
  this.enterpriseService
    .createEstablishmentAddress(this.addressFormGroup.getRawValue())
    .pipe(
      map((addressId) => addressId),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
        throwError(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.toastr.error(this.translatePipe.transform('COMPANY.DIALOGS.CREATE.ERROR-MSG.PERSISTENCE-ERROR'), this.translatePipe.transform('ADDRESS.DIALOGS.CREATE.TITLE'));
        })
      ),
      switchMap((addressId) => {
        enterpriseRM.establishment.addressId = addressId;
        this.entepriseWithEstablishmentFormGroup.controls.establishmentFormGroup.controls.addressId.patchValue(addressId);
        //this.showAddressForm = false;
        return this.enterpriseService.createEnterpriseWithEstablishment(enterpriseRM).pipe(
          map((response) => response),
          catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
            throwError(() => {
              this.isLoading = false;
              this.toastr.error(this.translatePipe.transform('COMPANY.DIALOGS.CREATE.ERROR-MSG'), this.translatePipe.transform('COMPANY.DIALOGS.CREATE.TITLE'));
            })
          )
        );
      })
    )
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.isLoading = false;

      if (response !== null) {
        this.dialogRef.close(response);
      }
    })
);
```

But as you know i have to do it for multiple establishments now.
The api to save adresses and the api to save enterprises/establishments is different.

Basically, the data i have is like this :

```
Enterprise : {
    socialReason: Apple;
    siren: 1248746392;
    establishment: [
      {
      name: Apple London;
      siret: 129838;
      addressId: null;
      enterpriseId: null;
      },
      { ...
    ]
}
```

And i can't save the establishment without addressId. I get what you said about letting the ORM manage the object but it's done like that and i have to deal with it .. (and i'm not a back-end dev)

Comment: Going to need to know what your data that you send to the server, and what the expected result is. Why is the creation of the enterprise detached from the creation of an establishment? You should just do all of it in one operation, when you click save it makes the enterprise AND saves the addresses. Let your ORM handle the mapping.

Comment: You should send all the data in one model...(Enterprise with List of Establishments) then have the back-end create the establishment records, get the created record's UIDs, and then create the Enterprise record.  (though really it seems like it should be the other way around... create the enterprise, then get it's UID, and then create the establishments each having an enterpriseID as the created Enterprise's UID.)

Comment: @SomeStudent Yes you are both right, and it's the case actually: I juste have to send the Enterprise object with the list of establishments. The problem is the addresses, i need to save them individually for each establishment, then get the adress id , update the Enterprise > EstablishmentList models and only then i can send the whole thing. I made an update to the question also

Comment: Can you send a list of addresses?  You need to chain in your subscribe calls to your services... so when results come back you make the next call to a service that returns an Observable, etc...  Ideally you'd send a list of addresses, and the back-end would return the same list with the IDs.

Comment: I believe you can notify with observables so you should be able to send each single create address check async and then do the rest when done...  (never done this myself, but maybe see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425813/notify-when-all-observables-are-completed )

Answer (score 1):

For future references, this was the answer i found and worked :

```
public onSave(): void {
this.isLoading = true;

const enterpriseFormGroup = etc...;
const enterpriseRM = etc...;

this.enterpriseService.createEnterprise(enterpriseRM).subscribe((enterpriseId: number) => {
  if (enterpriseId) {
    this.saveEstablishments(enterpriseId);
  }
});
}

private saveEstablishments(enterpriseId: number): void {
const siren = siren.value;
const establishmentList = this.getEstablishmentList(siren);

const apiCall = (establishment: EstablishmentWithAddress) =>
  this.enterpriseService.createEstablishmentAddress(establishment.address).pipe(
    map((addressId) => addressId),
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
      throwError(() => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.toastr.error(...);
      })
    ),
    mergeMap((addressId: number) => {
      const establishmentRM = new EstablishmentRequestModel(addressId);
      return this.enterpriseService.createEstablishment(establishmentRM).pipe(
        map((response) => response),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
          throwError(() => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.toastr.error(...);
          })
        )
      );
    })
  );

const apiCalls = Array.from(establishmentList, (v, i) => apiCall(v));
const numberOfSimultaneousRequests = 1;
let processedRows = 0;

this.subscriptions.add(
  of(...apiCalls)
    .pipe(mergeMap((savedData) => savedData, numberOfSimultaneousRequests))
    .subscribe({
      next: (savedData) => {
        processedRows++;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        if (processedRows === establishmentList.length) {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.dialogRef.close({
            id: enterpriseId,
            establishmentId: null,
          });
        }
      },
    })
);
}
```

The idea is to create an array of function calls (two functions chained with mergeMap, createAdress > create Establishment). And then call the array with the establishmentList and execute the array with mergeMap.

That was really a pain to develop