# Angular 16 RxJS : no idea how chain API

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a table of interventions and to get family name, i need to make another api call with familyId

```
[
    {
        "id": 14,
        "userId": 1,
        "familyId": 1,
        "family": null,
        "begin": "2023-11-01T07:00:00.000Z",
        "end": "2023-11-01T08:30:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-14T12:15:35.832Z",
        "deletedAt": null
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "userId": 1,
        "familyId": 1,
        "family": null,
        "begin": "2023-11-03T12:42:00.000Z",
        "end": "2023-11-03T14:42:00.000Z",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-14T12:43:11.706Z",
        "deletedAt": null
    }
]
```

How i can optimize it, today, i do a foreach after subscribe to `this.interventionsClient.get()` cuz i don't know very well rxjs

I want my table is like this :

| Intervention | Family name | Begin | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 14/12/2023 08:00 | 14/12/2023 10:00 |
| 2 | Test2 | 11/12/2023 08:00 | 11/12/2023 10:00 |
| 3 | Test | 10/12/2023 08:00 | 10/12/2023 10:00 |

For this i have `this.familyClient.getById()` and with this I try to fill each family attribute

Many thanks

Comment: The backend should optimize it's DB call to provide just the information you need.  Just the type that you need... match the backend/frontend types to match the table.

Comment: if you absolutely have to chain requests, you can foreach as you're doing now (you may want to include that code) or see the answer here for a clever chaining technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77317497/angular-wait-for-multiple-and-chained-request-then-make-a-final-post-request#comment136358312_77317497

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this blog](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a) for inspiration

Comment: I would take an approach using forkJoin: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin so you can make as many requests in parallel as possible.

Comment: Thanks to reply @Picci : I cannot show the blog

I do a forkJoin but if I have 100 item with familyId1 I have 100 requests, how I can optimize this ?

Comment: Here the right link https://medium.com/p/ef636c9af19a

Comment: Thanks, I made some stuff with your link, now I just need to solve identical request :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this with your tutorial and I have made this

```
    this.interventionsClient.getMonth(this.dateFilter)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(interventions => from(interventions)),
      mergeMap(intervention =>
        forkJoin([this.famillesClient.getById(intervention.familleId.toString())])
        .pipe(map(data => ({ intervention, famille: data[0]})))
      ),
      tap(data => data.intervention.famille = data.famille),
      map(data => data.intervention),
      toArray()
    ).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.interventions = data;
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
```

Dependencies are fetched ok, but I think I need caching cuz I have a lot of same api request

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**